# Just disabled Safe Boot trying to get broadcom wifi. No wireless networks (16.04.1 LTS)

Tags: networking, 16.04, broadcom

I finally figured out how to disable my Safe Boot (apparently this can be an issue in some cases), now I'm needing help for my next step. My menu bar doesn't even show the option for wireless networks. I have a Broadcom Wireless Adapter BCM4356. Any help?

Comment: Please paste  the output of the following command so that we can assist you further lspci -nn -d 14e4:

Comment: I think you meant `secure boot`, yes? Cheers, Al